# SQL Server case when date is null then select first then do another condition

Tags: sql-server, sorting, switch-statement, sql-order-by, row-number

I have a query where I am trying to do some conditions, but I always fail one out of the 3.
1st look if dischargedate is null then set order to 1, if dischargedate is not null then look into Rank column and pick the lowest rank and order by it. Query Below
For ClientId 3634164 I have 4 entries and works(picks the lowest rank as 1 as order of sort )
For ClientId 3634514 sees I have a dischargedate as null and that is our 1 order of sort
Where I fail is on ClientID 3634795, I have a dischargedate null but still picks the lowest rank as 1. How can I make it so that it picks the dischargedate as order of sort for that one?
The issue is with my sort only on ROW_NUMBER. In photo 1 and 2 pass but 3 the sort order 3 should be 1 [Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgBqZ.png)

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT PC.OP__DOCID AS LegacyClientProgramId,
       PC.ClientKey AS ClientId,
       PC.PgmKey AS ProgramId,
       CASE WHEN Date_Discharged_Program IS NULL THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS STATUS,
       PC.Date_Admit_Program AS RequestedDate,
       PC.Date_Admit_Program AS EnrolledDate,
       PC.Date_Discharged_Program AS DischargedDate,
       TX.RANK,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PC.ClientKey ORDER BY case when PC.Date_Discharged_Program 
                                                                      IS NULL THEN 0 
                                                                 when TX.Rank IS NOT NULL THEN 0 
                                                                 ELSE 1 END, TX.Rank) AS sortOrder
FROM FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT PC
LEFT JOIN LT__TXPLANHIERARCHY TX ON PC.PgmKey = TX.PgmKey
WHERE pc.ClientKey in ( SELECT ClientKey FROM LT__MIGRATE_CLIENT)
) SELECT LegacyClientProgramId,
         ClientId,
         ProgramId,
         STATUS,
         RequestedDate,
         EnrolledDate,
         DischargedDate,
         sortOrder,
         RANK,
         CASE WHEN sortOrder = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS PrimaryAssignment
         FROM CTE
         WHERE ProgramId <> 54
```

Comment: Posting screenshots of data is frown upon here. Why not write out the actual create table and insert some test data? Since it's probably easier to do for you that sits on the data and not to someone who has to reconstruct it from a picture

Comment: CASE Cod1 = 2 THEN Some END

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `0` to two different cases in your `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ORDER BY ...)` logic. This is placing `PC.Date_Discharged_Program IS NULL` and `TX.Rank IS NOT NULL` records at an equal starting position, with only `TX.Rank` acting as a tiebreaker. Since multiple rows have Rank = 60, the winner (`sortOrder 1`) is arbitrarily chosen.

Try:

```
... ORDER BY case when PC.Date_Discharged_Program IS NULL THEN 0 
                  when TX.Rank IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                  ELSE 2
                  END,
             TX.Rank) AS sortOrder
```